# Create an video gallery with UStream API

Tags: api

I'm trying to create a simple video gallery that pulls the videos from the recorded shows of a specific Ustream user.  I've been doing some research and looking at the [API Documentation](http://developer.ustream.tv/data_api/docs) but can't seem to figure it out.

This is what I have so far.

```
$request =  'http://api.ustream.tv';
$format = 'php';   // this can be xml, json, html, or php
$args .= 'subject=[channel]';
$args .= '&uid= [the-crossfader-show]';
$args .= '&command=[getCusomEmbedTag]';
$args .= '&params=[autoplay:false; mute:false; height:100; width:100;]';
$args .= '&page=[1]';
$args .= '&limit=[20]';
$args .= '&key=[4872929558631FEB4E9AEE8DDF080F28]';

// Get and config the curl session object
$session = curl_init($request.'/'.$format.'?'.$args);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute the request and close
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// this line works because we requested $format='php' and not some other output format
$resultsArray = unserialize($response);

// this is your data returned; you could do something more useful here than just echo it
print_r $resultsArray['result'];
```

I'm not really sure what to do after this to turn it into a simple gallery.  Anyone have any experience with the UStream API or have suggestions on what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I have been looking into the API myself for the first time today and came across this. Try using arguments without the square brackets around your values? example:

```
$args .= 'subject=channel';
$args .= '&uid=the-crossfader-show';
$args .= '&command=getCusomEmbedTag';
$args .= '&params=autoplay:false; mute:false; height:100; width:100;';
$args .= '&page=1';
$args .= '&limit=20';
$args .= '&key=4872929558631FEB4E9AEE8DDF080F28';
```

You also had an extra space before `the-crossfader-show`. I haven't tried this code, but perhaps this will help. Also, setting `subject=user` would get you all the videos for a user, vs `subject=channel` which i believe to only be a single video stream?

Comment: Following up on this for other people viewing. Using the command `listAllVideos` or `listAllChannels` will return an array of results with which you can build your video list from.